# ffmpeg overwrite output file if exists

Tags: ffmpeg

I ran:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac output.mp3
```

This prompts:

> File 'output.mp3' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y

How do I automatically say "yes"?

Answer (score 585, accepted):

Use the `-y` option to automatically overwrite [[docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)]:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.flac output.mp3
```

Comment: Alternatively there is also the `-n` option to automatically never overwrite files.

Comment: for YES -y and for NO -n.

Comment: Link to relevant documentation for those interested: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options

Answer (score 37):

I need to add the `-y` global switch before specifying the output file to accomplish this

```
ffmpeg -i /audio/191079007530_1_01.flac -t 51 -ss 69 -y /clips/44z274v23303t264y2z2s2s2746454t234_clip.mp3 2>&1 >> /ffmpegLogs.log
```

> Alternatively, you can use the `-n` option to deny overriding the
>   file.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, even right away. It helped me find the answer I was looking for - that's what SO is all about. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 25):

If there's someone using the [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) wrapper, then you can use `overwrite_output` arg when running the stream.

```py
stream = ffmpeg.input('dummy.mp4')
stream = ffmpeg.filter(stream, 'fps', fps=25, round='up')
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'dummy2.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream, overwrite_output=True)
```

Comment: was looking for this exact thing, thanks!

Comment: thnks, like to cmd docs: https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/

Comment: Exactly my use case, tysm! The only difference is that I was using it chained and without `stream`, like this: `...run(overwrite_output=True)`

Comment: glad to see my answer helps many people out there ^^