# Subprocess: How to capture process still running with yes/no prompt " File 'x' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]"

Tags: python, subprocess

When the process is running we can use `returncode` to check its state.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
   retrun_code =p.wait()
   print(retrun_code)
```

The documentation for the [returncode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) attribute says:

> The child return code, set by `poll()` and `wait()` . if it is `None` value indicates that **the process hasn’t terminated yet**.

I am running FFmpeg commands using a subprocess. In some cases, when a file already exists, it will prompt to confirm overwrite.

`File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]`

Similar to return code, how can I check when  the prompt is shown in the process?
More Precisely, How do I tell if process is running or waiting for user input?

Comment: You'd have to a program that concurrently & continuously processes `stdout` and `stdin` like a human would, which would be notably more complex. It'd be much easier to choose ahead of time whether to always/never overwrite existing files, passing in `-y`/`-n` option accordingly, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788972/ffmpeg-overwrite-output-file-if-exists

Answer (score 0):

wrap your command with the `yes` command.

`yes | ffmpeg -blah`

or use the -y flag on ffmpeg.